# i18next uses fallback instead of using other client's accept-language

Tags: node.js, i18next

Node + EJS app, using `i18next-fs-backend` and `i18next-http-middleware`.
Supported locales: `en`, `fr` (retreived via backend).

When client's *accept-language* is `[fr]` it translates correctly to French, and otherwise to English.
But when *accept-language* is `[es, fr]`, it directly falls back to English (instead of using French).

```js
[...]
const i18next = require('i18next'),
      i18next_backend = require('i18next-fs-backend'),
      i18next_middleware = require('i18next-http-middleware');

i18next
    .use(i18next_backend)
    .use(i18next_middleware.LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        preload: ['en', 'fr'],
        fallbackLng: 'en',
        backend: {
            loadPath: path.join(__dirname, '/locales/{{ns}}-{{lng}}.json')
        }, debug: true
    });

app.use(i18next_middleware.handle(i18next));
```

Is there a way to make it look for other accept-languages, and in this case use French?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `supportedLngs: ['en', 'fr']` to the init options (and `nonExplicitSupportedLngs: true` to get the `fr-FR` → `fr` behavior back) solves it.

(Only found a clue to this [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/351), after too many (probably bad) Google searches.)